# Need code in C# .net to read rfid tag values in windows mobile emulator

Tags: windows-mobile, rfid, windows-mobile-emulator

I have used the code below to read rfid tag values.

```
try
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM25";

    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
    serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 5;
    serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;

    serialPort1.Open();
    lblStatus.Text = "Serial Port: Connected";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Serial Port: Unable to Connect";
}
```

The above code is working for windows application but when i use the same code in windows mobile emulator it is saying unable to connect serial port. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the actual message text on the exception being thrown?  That may give you some insight as to the root cause.  I suspect it may have something to do with the assumption that you've got a serial port available on the mobile device named "COM25."

Comment: It is not able to connect to the serial port when i am running the code in emulator. The same code is working perfectly when i am running it in a windows form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some specific configuration with the emulator to enable ports. See [here for a good, starter article](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/38500).

Googling [how to configure windows mobile emulator serial port](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=how%20to%20configure%20windows%20mobile%20emulator%20serial%20port&oq=how%20to%20configure%20windows%20mobile%20emulator%20serial%20port&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_l=hp.3...18884l20014l2l21100l8l8l0l0l0l3l139l802l5j3l8l0.eqn.1.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9b0c83a130f3bca0&ix=seb&ion=1&biw=1308&bih=721) for will also yield some things to look at.